# Shiny gives empty plot

Tags: r, shiny

strggeling a bit with setting up the shiny. Not sure where the error occurs, please see info below:

Get the following error related to facet_grid:

```
Warning: Error in combine_vars: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `input$Cancer`
✖ Plot is missing `input$Cancer`
✖ Layer 1 is missing `input$Cancer`
```

However, if I remove facet_grid, it produces an empty plot, so I think something is wrong with either `selectInput`, `data_selected` or the `ggplot`

example data:

```
 files.Vir.DNA.df.test <- structure(list(ID = c("NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", 
"NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", 
"NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", 
"NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2", 
"NC_010277.2", "NC_010277.2"), rowSums = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    Cancer = c("Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", 
    "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", 
    "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", 
    "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", 
    "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", "Adrenal gland", 
    "Adrenal gland"), position = c(1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 
    1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 
    1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019), V1 = c("Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", 
    "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", 
    "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", 
    "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", 
    "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", 
    "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", 
    "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", 
    "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", 
    "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", 
    "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b", 
    "Merkel_cell_polyomavirus_isolate_R17b"), Length = c(5387L, 
    5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 
    5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 5387L, 
    5387L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20"), class = "data.frame")
```

ui:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  # Application title
  dashboardHeader(title=h4(HTML("Virus Coverage plot"))),
  dashboardSidebar(
    useShinyjs(),
    
    selectInput("Taxa", "Taxa", choices = unique(files.Vir.DNA.df.test$V1)),
    shinyjs::hidden(selectInput("Taxa", "Taxa", choices = c("Taxa")))
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Taxa", plotOutput("myplot1", width = "400px", height = "300px"))
      
    )
  )
)
```

server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_selected <- reactive({
    filter(files.Vir.DNA.df.test, V1 %in% input$V1)
  })
  
  output$myplot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data_selected(), aes_string(input$V1, "position", fill = input$V1)) + 
        scale_y_log10(breaks = c(1,100,10000)) +
        theme_classic(base_size = 6) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        facet_grid(Cancer~. , scales = "free_x", space = "free_x", switch = "x") 

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The first issue with your code is that you use `input$V1` whereas the inputId of your selectInput is `Taxa`, i.e. use `input$Taxa`. Second, using `input$V1` (or `input$Taxa` in your ggplot code makes no sense, as `input$Taxa` isn't a column name but contains the categories of the column `V1` in your data. Finally, note that `aes_string` was deprecated in `ggplot2 3..4.0`. Instead it is recommended to use the `.data` pronoun. See `?aes_string`.

Comment: "input$Taxa isn't a column name but contains the categories of the column V1 in your data." Thus is true and probably the main issue here. Do you have a suggestion how to select different Taxa based on the values in files.Vir.DNA.df.test$V1

Comment: I think you could simply do `ggplot(data_selected(), aes(V1, position, fill = V1))` to display the selected categories on the x axis and fill by category.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments there are quite a few issues with the code but the following will produce the graph for based on selected taxa. I am not quite sure what you are trying to do with `shinyjs::hidden` there.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  # Application title
  dashboardHeader(title=h4(HTML("Virus Coverage plot"))),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    selectInput("Taxa", "Taxa", choices = unique(files.Vir.DNA.df.test$V1))
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Taxa", 
               plotOutput("myplot1", width = "400px", height = "300px"))
      
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_selected <- reactive({
    filter(files.Vir.DNA.df.test, V1 %in% input$Taxa)
  })
  
  output$myplot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data_selected(), aes(V1, position, fill = V1)) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
      scale_y_log10(breaks = c(1,100,10000)) +
      theme_classic(base_size = 6) +
      facet_grid(Cancer~. , scales = "free_x", space = "free_x", switch = "x")
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```